# How to select an option from SELECT using selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in python. I really wonder how to get my option from a SELECT. In the case listed below, I would like to select the first option of the SELECT tag.

I have tried many ways but they all failed. The error currently is "Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated". Using index their is no error but nothing is displayed

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r"C:\Users\dongyx\Downloads\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get("https://studentcare.scse.ntu.edu.sg/sc1/f4_pt_pubass_attendance.php")
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.find_element_by_id("UID").send_keys("dong0096")
driver.find_element_by_name("PWORD").send_keys("Boris@21")

driver.find_element_by_name("SUBMIT").click()

time.sleep(3)
#print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').decode())

driver.get("https://studentcare.scse.ntu.edu.sg/sc1/f4_pt_pubass_attendance.php")
print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').decode())
driver.find_element_by_name('FilterBy')
sele_obj = driver.find_element_by_name('FilterBy') 
select = Select(sele_obj)
for opt in select.options:
    print(opt.get_attribute("index"))
print(select.options[1])
select._setSelected(select.options[1])
#select.select_by_index("1")


all_submits = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='SUBMIT']")
print(all_submits[0].get_attribute('name'))
all_submits[0].submit()

print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').decode())
```

The output without the printed source code is like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c7025190-d49e- 
11e9-941d-a713501df08a", element=":wdc:1568211407446")
```

This is the source code of the website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scheduler.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sddmenu/sddmenu.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="ddmenu/ddmenu.css" /> -->


<div class='center_header_div'><div id='ui_staff_header_container'><div id='ui_header_title_container'><p id='ui_header_title1'>NTU SCSE STUDENT CARE SYSTEM</p><p id='ui_header_title2'> </p></div></div></div><div class='ui_nav_container'><p id='ui_nav_left'>Welcome <b>Dong Yunxing</b> (Last Login: 2019-09-11 14:51:55)</p><p id='ui_nav_right'><a href='form_welcome.php'> Main </a> |
                <a href='form_help.php'> Contact Us </a> |
                <a href='logout.php'> Logout </a></p></div>

<noscript>
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
    <div style="margin:auto; text-align:center; color:red">
        This site is best viewed with Javascript. Please turn on Javascript to use this site.
    </div>
</div>
</noscript>





<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.css" />
<script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablesorter/themes/style.css" />
<script src="tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="datetime/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>

div.ui-datepicker{
    font-size:12px;
}


/* css for timepicker */
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt { float: left; clear:left; padding: 0 0 0 5px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 45%; }
.ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
.ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.ui-timepicker-rtl{ direction: rtl; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl { text-align: right; padding: 0 5px 0 0; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dt{ float: right; clear: right; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd { margin: 0 45% 10px 10px; }

</style>


<script>
    /*
    $(function() {
        $( "#Date1" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: "+1w", minDate: +1, maxDate: "+1M +1D" });
    });
      */

    $(function() {

                $('[name="FilterBy"]').chosen({ search_contains:true });
                $( "#Date1" ).datepicker({ minDate: '-120d', maxDate: '+120d', dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', altField: '#Date1' });
                $( "#Date2" ).datepicker({ minDate: '-120d', maxDate: '+121d', dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', altField: '#Date2' });

                $('.datepick').each(function(){ $(this).datetimepicker( {minDate: '-14d', maxDate: '+120d', dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'} ); $(this).attr('readOnly', 'true'); });
                //$('.datepick').each(function(){ $(this).datetimepicker('setDate', new Date()); });


    });


      display_alert = false;

        function toggle(source) {
            //checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('delpub');
            checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
            for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }




        function Save_Only(event) {
            //var eid = $(event.target).attr('id');
            var eid = event.id;
            if(display_alert) { alert("Called by " + eid); }

            sign_attend(eid);



        }



        function Attend(event) {
            //var eid = $(event.target).attr('id');
            var eid = event.id;
            if(display_alert) { alert("Called by " + eid); }

            var eid_arr = eid.split("_");
            var type = eid_arr[0];
            var cid = eid_arr[1];
            var sid = eid_arr[2];
            var rid = eid_arr[3];

            schedule_class_attend(eid);

            var allid = cid + "_" + sid + "_" + rid;

            document.getElementById("Remarks_" + allid).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("attend_" + allid).disabled = true;
        }




        function schedule_class_attend(event){

            var eid = event;
            if(display_alert) { alert("Called by " + eid); }

            var eid_arr = eid.split("_");
            var type = eid_arr[0];
            var cid = eid_arr[1];
            var sid = eid_arr[2];
            var rid = eid_arr[3];

            var allid = cid + "_" + sid + "_" + rid;

            var S_Remarks = document.getElementById("Remarks_" + allid).value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "btnajax_pt_pubass_attendance.php",
                data: {
                    "Selected_Remarks": S_Remarks,
                    "Selected_Type": type,
                    "Selected_CID": cid,
                    "Selected_SID": sid,
                    "Selected_RID": rid,
                }, 
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(responseData) {

                    var rpd  = responseData.trim();
                    //alert("Response: [" + rpd + "]");

                    if(rpd >= 1){

                        document.getElementById("Status_" + type + "_" + allid).innerHTML = "ok";
                        //alert("Records Stored");
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("Status_" + type + "_" + allid).innerHTML = rpd;
                        //alert("Error Found");
                    }
                }
            });

        }





        $(document).ready(function() 
                { 

                    $("#SortThisTable").tablesorter();
            /*
                    $("#SortThisTable").tablesorter({

                        headers: { 
                            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
                            1: { 
                                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                                sorter: false 
                            }, 
                        }


                    });
                */ 
            }

        );


</script>



</head>







<!-- <p></p> -->
<!-- <h2>Welcome</h2> -->


<p></p>

<div class="center_menu_div">


<ul id="nav" class="drop">














 <li>Forms
    <ul>
      <li><a href="create_new_tutee.php" target="_blank">Register for Peer Teaching Support as a Tutee</a></li>
      <li><a href="create_new_tutor.php" target="_blank">Register for Peer Teaching Support as a Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="create_new_coach.php" target="_blank">Register for Peer Teaching Support as a Coach</a></li>
      <li><a href="create_new_feedback.php" target="_blank">Send Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="create_new_counsellee.php" target="_blank">Register for counseling with SCSE Student Care</a></li>
      <li><a href="create_new_alumni.php" target="_blank">Register as SCSE Alumni</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li>Publication Assignment (Tutoring)
    <ul>
      <li><a href="f4_pt_pubass_new_schedule.php">Create Class Schedule</a></li>
      <li><a href="f4_pt_pubass_attendance.php">Mark Attendance</a></li>
      <li><a href="f4_pt_pubass_mucl.php">Meetup Coordinator Log</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>





















</ul>


</div>



<div class="center_div">

<p></p>
<h2 style="padding-right:20px; border-bottom:1px solid black; position:relative; width:1400px; color: #606060; ">Mark Attendance</h2>
<h3 style='color: #989898;'>Please enter the following information:</h3>



<form action="/sc1/f4_pt_pubass_attendance.php" METHOD="POST">

<br>



<span style='font-size:8px;'> E-SignatureX: 77777777<br>(<i>As of 2019/09/11 03:39 pm</i>)</span><br><br>



<table style='width:1700px;'>



    <tr>
        <td style='width:154px;text-align:right;font-size:13px;'>Select Type <font color='red'>*</font>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style='padding:4px 0px 7px 0px;'>
        <SELECT name="FilterBy" style="width: 1110px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value='2019-1-18-130-76-580'>[2019-1-18-130-76-580] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20190911 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-581'>[2019-1-18-130-76-581] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20190918 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-582'>[2019-1-18-130-76-582] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20190925 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-583'>[2019-1-18-130-76-583] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20191009 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-584'>[2019-1-18-130-76-584] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20191016 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-585'>[2019-1-18-130-76-585] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20191023 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-586'>[2019-1-18-130-76-586] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20191030 from 1830 to 2030</option><option value='2019-1-18-130-76-587'>[2019-1-18-130-76-587] AY 2019-2020 Semester 1 CE1011/CZ1011 ( Engineering Mathematics I ) 20191106 from 1830 to 2030</option>            </SELECT>
                    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:154px;text-align:right;font-size:13px;'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:154px;text-align:right;font-size:13px;'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Proceed"></input>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Export to Excel"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:154px;text-align:right;font-size:13px;'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>




</table>




 <table style='width:1700px;'>   




</table>

</form>

</div>
```

I notice that actually it manages to detect all the 8 options of the select but just when trying to update the option some error occurs.

More specifically the error is (in case is useful but very hard to read)

```py
Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:51498","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0 (python windows)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1568211407446\", \"sessionId\": \"c7025190-d49e-11e9-941d-a713501df08a\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c7025190-d49e-11e9-941d-a713501df08a/element/:wdc:1568211407446/click"}}
```

Screenshot: available via screen

I really wonder why the _setSelected cannot work here, from the traceback it seems when it tries to do `Command.CLICK_ELEMENT` the exception is generated. Is it because I nid to click select tag first then all the options can be displayed 
to be clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me concerning the Select() function you're using. So when I look at the errormessage it's giving (possible) a hint for a solution. It cannot find (at that point in the script/in time) the element it looks for.

Since you're not (yet) letting the webdriver wait for the element/at all, it's allways possible that the webdriver is faster than the DOM or particular elements can pull up.

I suggest you try waiting for the element to solve this.

There are multiple ways of waiting for an element.

---

***Method 1 (implicit wait):***

You tell it to poll the DOM for a maximium time (in seconds). When it can't find the element you're looking it will raise a NoSuchElementException.

you can do so at top of your script after defining the webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r"C:\Users\dongyx\Downloads\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs")
driver.implicit_wait(15)
```

---

***Method 2 (explicit wait):***

Wait for specific elements in particular. We tell it to wait until some specific conditions are met (we use Excpected conditions for this)

NOTE: You need import some extra modules for this.

example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
men_menu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-tracking-id='men']")))


fastrack = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-tracking-id='0_Fastrack']")));
```

see docs on 'waits': https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Please let me know if 'waits' help solving your issue!

Comment: Hi Ewald, I have tried your first approach (but failed) and editted my code (which may help). I am still trying your second approach but it seems not to be the issue of waiting time.